# Mongoose doesn't save the array after quitting .map(...) loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this issue where whenever Node.js quits the `.map(...)` loop my `Post.attachments` array rolls back to the `[]` state. I wonder why this happens.

Here's my code

```js
req.files.map(async (file) => {
    const _FILENAME_ = uniqid(); // Generating a unique filename
    const _FILEPATH_ = `${AuthorAccount._id}/media/${_FILENAME_}`;

    await MinIO.client.fPutObject(MinIO.bucket, _FILEPATH_, file.path, {
          "Content-Type": file.mimetype
    });
    const PresignedURL = await MinIO.client.presignedGetObject(MinIO.bucket, _FILEPATH_);

    const _ATTACHMENT_ = {};
    _ATTACHMENT_.url = PresignedURL;
    _ATTACHMENT_.filename = _FILENAME_;

    Post.attachments.push(_ATTACHMENT_);
    unlinkSync(path.resolve(file.path));
});

AuthorAccount.posts.push(Post);
await AuthorAccount.save();
return res.json(Post);
```

I have 2 subdocuments: `Post` and `Post.attachments`

Here's the attachment schema which is nested in `Post`

```js
const AttachmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url: { type: String },
  filename: { type: String }
});
```

and in `Post.js` I included it like this

```json
{
  ...,
  attachments: [AttachmentSchema],
  ...
}
```

Whenever I log `Post.attachments` everything works fine, it shows that there are items in the array but when the `.map(...)` ends and I log the array afterwards nothing seems to work.

Hope we'll be able to resolve this issue and understand why this happens.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the `.map` statement, node will not wait until the mapping has finished, it will just continue executing with the next statement, i.e. `AuthorAccount.posts.push(Post);`

Since you are not actually mapping something, you can just use a `for..of` loop, which will take your `awaits` inside into account, meaning that the executing will not continue after the loop until it has been processed asynchronously:

```
// ...
for (const file of req.files) {
    const _FILENAME_ = uniqid(); // Generating a unique filename
    const _FILEPATH_ = `${AuthorAccount._id}/media/${_FILENAME_}`;

    await MinIO.client.fPutObject(MinIO.bucket, _FILEPATH_, file.path, {
        "Content-Type": file.mimetype
    });
    const PresignedURL = await MinIO.client.presignedGetObject(MinIO.bucket, _FILEPATH_);

    const _ATTACHMENT_ = {};
    _ATTACHMENT_.url = PresignedURL;
    _ATTACHMENT_.filename = _FILENAME_;

    Post.attachments.push(_ATTACHMENT_);
    unlinkSync(path.resolve(file.path));
});

AuthorAccount.posts.push(Post);
// rest of the code
```